# Multiple `if` statements in bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm trying to write a short bash script that optionally accepts arguments from the command line, or prompts for their input

```
if [ [ -z "$message" ] && [ -z "$predefined" ] ] ; then
  read -p "Enter message [$defaultMessage]: " message
  message=${message:-$defaultMessage}
else
  if [ -n "$predefined" ]; then
    if [ -f $base/$environment/vle/data/$predefined.txt ]; then
      echo Predefined message file $predefined.txt does not exist
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
fi
```

If neither `message` nor `predefined` has been passed in as command line arguments, then the code should prompt for a value for `message`; otherwise if `predefined` has been passed in as a command line argument, then the script should test for the existence of a file of that name and only continue if the file does exist

But I'm getting the following error

```
[: -z: binary operator expected
```

at the first of those `if` tests

Any help in explaining what's wrong with my syntax for that first `if` statement? Or providing an alternative syntax to achieve the same objectives.

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) is often helpful for diagnosing these kinds of issues, as described in the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info)

Comment: @thatotherguy - thanks, I'll keep that link in mind whenever I'm writing shell scripts

Comment: Also note that you can run it [locally and in your editor](http://www.shellcheck.net/about.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first `if` is not well-formed. This would work:

```
if [ -z "$message" ] && [ -z "$predefined" ]; then
```

or this:

```
if test -z "$message" && test -z "$predefined"; then
```

or this bash-specific, easy but dirty way:

```
if [[ -z "$message" ]] && [[ -z "$predefined" ]]; then
```

or this bash-specific proper way:

```
if [[ -z $message && -z $predefined ]]; then
```

In this last version the double-quotes are unnecessary, not a typo.

Thanks [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for the corrections in the bash-specific style, and for this final comment:

> I should note that there's one case where double-quoting is still a must inside `[[ ... ]]`, namely if you want a variable reference on the right side of a string comparison (`==`) to be treated as a literal:
>
> ```
> v='[a]'
> [[ $v == $v ]] # FALSE!
> [[ $v == "$v" ]] # true
> ```
>
> Without double-quoting, the right-hand side is interpreted as a pattern. Some people advocate always double-quoting variable references so as not to have to remember such subtleties. That said (from bash 3.2 on), you must NOT double-quote the right operand when regex matching with `=~`

Comment: The 1st and 3rd snippet retain POSIX compatibility, but the 2nd, bash-specific one, can be simplified to: `if [[ -z $message && -z $predefined ]]; then;` - i.e.: `&&` _inside_ `[[ ... ]]`; also, using `[[ ... ]]` obviates the need to double-quote.

Comment: Nice, thanks @mklement0, I corrected my answer based on your comment

Comment: Thanks for updating; +1; I should note that there's one case where double-quoting is still a must inside `[[ ... ]]`,namely if you want a variable reference on the _right_ side of a string comparison (`==`) to be treated as a _literal_: `v='[a]'; [[ $v == $v ]] # FALSE!`; `[[ $v == "$v" ]] # true`. Without double-quoting, the right-hand side is interpreted as a _pattern_. Some people advocate _always_ double-quoting variable references so as not to have to remember such subtleties. That said (from bash 3.2 on), you must NOT double-quote the right operand when regex matching with `=~`.

Answer (score 4):

```
test expression1 -a expression2
```

is true if both expressions are true.

```
test expression1 -o expression2
```

is true if either or both expressions are true.

```
if [ -z "$message" -a -z "$predefined" ]; then
    read -p "Enter message [$defaultMessage]: " message
    message=${message:-$defaultMessage}
else
    if [ -n "$predefined" -a -f $base/$environment/vle/data/$predefined.txt ]; then
        echo Predefined message file $predefined.txt does not exist
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

This was able to combine 4 test into 2 while also getting rid of one nested if expression; then ; fi